# Compare 2 df's df1and df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

compare 2 df's df1 is having 1000+ rows with repeated unique_id's but df2 having only unique unique_id's.each and every row in df1 i want to compare to df2 so that unique_id is there in df2 if matched  compare same category and subcategory as well from df1 to df2.
output : should be if unmatched any of those then pick that index into an array.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'unique_id': 
        ['Computer','iPhone','Printer','Desktop','Computer','iPhone','iphpne','Printer','Desktop','Computer','iPhone','Printer','Desktop'],
        'category': 
         ['movies','documentary','series','special','movies','documentary','series','special','series','special','movies','series','special'],
         'subcategory':
         ['drama','horror','comedy','reality','drama','documentary','comedy','reality','documentary','comedy','documentary','comedy','drama']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns= ['unique_id', 'category','subcategory'])


data2 = {'unique_id': ['Computer','iPhone','Printer','Desktop'],
         'category': ['movies','documentary','series','special'],
         'subcategory':['drama','horror','comedy','reality']
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns= ['unique_id', 'category','subcategory'])
```

Comment: Whats stopping you to join the dataframes using `unique id`?

Comment: Pls give your expected output. The problem statement and expectation is not quite clear.

Comment: i tried looping through each and every row in df1 with df2 but iam getting error.As df1 having 1200 rows but df2 having only 20 rows

Comment: i mean df2 having only unique values but df1 having with 1 unique_id multiple rows with difeerent category and sub category fields .need to check df1 each row is values are matching with df2.if unmatched then pickup index.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Prints:

```
   unique_id     category  subcategory
5     iPhone  documentary  documentary
6     iphpne       series       comedy
7    Printer      special      reality
8    Desktop       series  documentary
9   Computer      special       comedy
10    iPhone       movies  documentary
12   Desktop      special        drama
```

**To get the index**

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).index
```

Prints:

```
   Int64Index([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: @pushpa is this wat you need?